# Cannot discard local changes

Tags: git

I have tried everything to discard local changes. I don't need any of the changes. I want to discard everything. I have tried:

```
git checkout .
git reset
git reset HARD
git clean -f
```

But no matter what i try, when i run git status I see:

```
On branch release/3.12
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/release/3.12'.

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

public/src/javascripts/views/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

And I cannot switch branches because of these changes. How can I simply discard the local changes?

Comment: try `git clean -xfd`

Comment: According to the status message you don't have changes in any file that is tracked, but you have files that is not yet added to git (use plain `rm public/src/javascripts/views/` if you need to remove these files). What do you get when you try to switch branches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to also clean untracked folders, you have to [do](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git+clean+-fd):

```
git clean -fd
```

I suggest you first run `git clean -nd`, to preview the outcome of the clean operation.

Answer (score 1):

The changes in your current repository are related to a folder containing untracked files. To delete them, you can delete the folder

```
rm -fr public/src/javascripts/views/
```

or you can use git clean

```
git clean -fd .
```